# Fine and Replace Array in YAML file with yq

Tags: yq

On my Mac I have `yq` and I want to change the following YAML file:

```
---
- type: replace
  path: /mypath1
  value:
  - "10.244.1.4"
- type: replace
  path: /mypath2
  value:
    - value1
- type: replace
  path: /mypath3
  value:
    - value1
 - type: remove
   path: /mypath4
```

Now I need to change this block:

```
 - type: replace
   path: /mypath2
   value:
     - value1
```

with this:

```
 - type: replace
   path: /mypath2
   value:
     - value2
     - value3
```

But I am not able to find the right `yq w ...` command to do this. I searched lots of examples on the web, even on StackOverflow but no luck.
The best solution would be that when "path==/mypath2" I can set the value field with another array.
Any suggestion?

Comment: The input shown is not valid YAML - http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Yes, you're right. I correct it, but this is not the issue. I tried a lot of examples but no luck, really don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption

There is missing space in front of the last index (line 16). To test the following script, use the yaml file bellow:

```
---
- type: replace
  path: /mypath1
  value:
    - "10.244.1.4"
- type: replace
  path: /mypath2
  value:
    - value1
- type: replace
  path: /mypath3
  value:
    - value1
- type: remove
  path: /mypath4
- type: remove
  path: test
```

From your example (`yq w...`), I assume you are using yq3.

### Exemple

The first thing to do is to find the correct query to isolate the array you want to write to. I used the `path` property to isolate the correct index since it seems to be a unique identifier.

```
$ yq r file.yml '(path==/mypath2).value'
- value1
```

Now that we have the correct **read** query, it is easier to figure out the **write** query. Use the `[+]` operator to append new value to an existing array.

```
$ yq w file.yml '(path==/mypath2).value[+]' "value3"
- type: replace
  path: /mypath1
  value:
    - "10.244.1.4"
- type: replace
  path: /mypath2
  value:
    - value1
    - value3
- type: replace
  path: /mypath3
  value:
    - value1
- type: remove
  path: /mypath4
- type: remove
  path: test
```

You can add the `-i, --inplace` option to update file.yml directly.